# baselineskip in ohead?

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

My header has 2 lines. How do I reduce the line spacing there?

MWE:

```
% --- Page Layout, Header, Footer --- %
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt, parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
  footsepline=0.25pt, headsepline=0.25pt,
  % automark places section title in header. Also enables placement in footer.
  automark]
{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[a4paper,
  vmargin=2cm, hmargin=2cm, % page margins
  includehead, includefoot, % Margins calculated include header and footer
  footskip=2em]
{geometry}

% Header content
\ohead{{\baselineskip=0pt \tiny{Line1 \\ Line2}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Testing}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick and dirty solution, you could add a negative `\baselineskip` to `\\`.

```
% --- Page Layout, Header, Footer --- %
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt, parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
  footsepline=0.25pt, headsepline=0.25pt,
  % automark places section title in header. Also enables placement in footer.
  automark]
{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[a4paper,
  vmargin=2cm, hmargin=2cm, % page margins
  includehead, includefoot, % Margins calculated include header and footer
  footskip=2em]
{geometry}

% Header content
\ohead{{\tiny Line1 \\[-\baselineskip] Line2}}

\begin{document}
\section{Testing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a table in `\ohead`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt, parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
  footsepline=0.25pt, headsepline=0.25pt,
  automark]
{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[
  margin=2cm, % page margins
  includeheadfoot, % Margins calculated include header and footer
  footskip=2em]
{geometry}

% Header content
\ohead{\tiny
  \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
    Line1\\Line2
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Testing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or you could use a `\parbox`:

```
% Header content
\ohead{\parbox{\linewidth}{\raggedleft\tiny Line1 \\ Line2}}
```

Another suggestion is changing the fontsize of the header to `\tiny`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt, parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
  footsepline=0.25pt, headsepline=0.25pt,
  automark]
{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[
  margin=2cm, % page margins
  includeheadfoot, % Margins calculated include header and footer
  footskip=2em]
{geometry}

% Header content
\ohead{Line1 \\ Line2}
\chead{\normalsize\headmark}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\tiny}

\begin{document}
\section{Testing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably the `tabular` method is the best.